# Segmentation Fault w/ fwrite

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fwrite

I've a problem with the `fwrite` function (I checked it using debugging on C::B).
This is the code:

```
struct  studente
{   char Cognome_Nome[30];
    char Matricola [11];
    short Superati;
    float Media_Pesata;
    short Crediti;
};
typedef struct studente STUDENTE;

void main()
{   FILE *fp;
    STUDENTE Dati;

    if((fp = fopen("studente.dat","w+b")) == NULL)
        printf("Error\n");
    else
    {   fflush(stdin);
        printf("Inserire il cognome e nome: ");
        fgets(Dati.Cognome_Nome, 30, stdin);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nInserire la matricola: ");
        fgets(Dati.Matricola, 11, stdin);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Inserire il numero di esami superati: ");
        scanf("%hd", &Dati.Superati);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Inserire la media pesata: ");
        scanf("%f", &Dati.Media_Pesata);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Inserire il numero di crediti: ");
        scanf("%hd", &Dati.Crediti);

        fwrite(&Dati, sizeof(STUDENTE), 1, fp);
    }
}
```

I receive an Segmentation Fault when `fwrite` is called. I can't understand where is the problem. I checked the `fwrite` prototype and I think it's all right.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Plz Refer the following discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: Maybe your system is old and does not understand the `'h'` in `"%h..."`?  What OS?

Comment: @ Jeyaram I've used fflush() just for trying. I use a _fflush() function that I found on the web. 

@chux I use Windows 8 but also with the last Ubuntu, the code doesn't work.

Comment: You have done `#include <stdio>.h>`? Otherwise odd things might happen. Also, it should be `int main`, but that's unlikely to cause your problem.

Comment: 1) If system does not understand the 'h', change to `int i; scanf("%d", &i); Dati.Superati = i;` and same for `Dati.Crediti`.  2) More detail on "code doesn't work" - do you mean it also seg faults.? 3) sorry I asked what OS - meant to ask what compiler?

Comment: Yes, I have included     <stdio.h> and I use    int main(), but, nothing to do. It doesn't work.

Comment: instead of fwrite(&Dati, sizeof(STUDENTE), 1, fp), try fwrite(&Dati, 1, sizeof(STUDENTE), fp). that might work

Comment: @ralph It _might_ help but `size_t fwrite(const void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * restrict stream);` (`nmemb` elements
whose size is specified by `size`) and OP appears to be calling it correctly.  For style: I would recommend `fwrite(&Dati, sizeof Dati, 1, fp);`, but that is not the major issue here.

Comment: @chux, i know its correct, was just trying a workaround. :)

Comment: At least VC10 doesn't support the length modifier `'h'`.

Comment: I resolved changing the '%hd' in '%d'

Comment: Changing `"%hd"` to `"%d"` is not good unless the fields are changed also from `short` to `int`.

Comment: have you checked the exact code you've posted on ubuntu? it works fine on mine

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler (e.g VC10 @alk) does not understand the `'h'` in format specifiers which, which I believe, is a C99 addition.  3 solutions:

1. Change to a new compiler.
2. Read the `short` via a temporary variable.

   ```
   int i;
   scanf("%d", &i);
   Dati.Superati = i;
   ```
3. Make the 2 fields `int` rather than `short` and use `"%d"`

   ```
   struct  studente {
      ...
      int Superati;
      int Crediti;
   } 
   ...
   scanf("%d", &Dati.Superati);
   ...
   scanf("%d", &Dati.Crediti);
   ```

---

Other minor suggestions:

```
// @ Tom Tanner
// void main()
int main(void)

// Avoid magic numbers
// fgets(Dati.Cognome_Nome, 30, stdin);
fgets(Dati.Cognome_Nome, sizeof Dati.Cognome_Nome, stdin);

// @ Jeyaram
// Do not use fflush(stdin). Better methods exist to handle stray input data
// fflush(stdin);

// Less error prone and easier to maintain code
// fwrite(&Dati, sizeof(STUDENTE), 1, fp);
fwrite(&Dati, sizeof Dati, 1, fp);

// Check I/O function results
```

Comment: Good call. That's what I was thinking.  The `scanf` into the final field, Crediti, is stomping on `fp` which likely appears immediately after Crediti in the stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what is happening is this:

A call to `fgets()` or `scanf()` is storing data beyond the structure `Dati`.  This stomps on the `fp` pointer variable, which is likely stored immediately after `Dati` on the stack frame.  Then you call `fwrite()` which dereferences `fp` and *boom* you have undefined behavior and a segmentation fault.

I bet if you comment out all `scanf` and `fgets` functions that store into `Dati` and replace them with hard-coded assignments to `Dati` fields, you'll see that the crash is fixed.

Comment: which `fgets()` or `scanf()` are you thinking of? They all look good to me

Comment: Right, I think they look good. But I bet that `fp` is getting stomped by someone, and that's the only thing I see as a possibility.